# In r how to make a pipeline with 2 parts of a data frame as parameters of a function?

Tags: r, pipeline, zoo

I'm trying to do a pipeline like:

```
df <- df %>% 
         .....some functions pass df as first parameter....
         zoo(???) %>%
          .....some functions pass df as first parameter....
```

Because at the step zoo(), it requires df[, some_columns] as first parameter, and df$a_index as second column, how I can write into this pipeline? If I don't want to break the pipeline into:

```
df <- df %>% .... 
df <- zoo(df[, some_columns], df$a_index)
df <- df %>% ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Using the built-in `BOD` data frame as an example the easiest is to form the zoo object using `read.zoo` like this:

```
library(dplyr) # library(magrittr) would also work for this example
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

BOD %>%
    read.zoo() %>%
    autoplot()
```

**2)** however, if you really wanted to use the zoo constructor then this works (with the same `library` statements):

```
BOD %>% 
    { zoo(.[[[2]], .[[1]]) } %>% 
    autoplot()
```

If `BOD` has more than 2 columns then use .[-1] as the first argument.

**3)** This also works.

```
BOD %>%
    { zoo(.$demand, .$Time) } %>%
    autoplot
```

**4)**  This also works:

```
library(magrittr) # must use magrittr

BOD %$%  # note that this is a different pipe operator
    zoo(demand, Time) %>%
    autoplot()
```

Comment: So cooool! So the {} is meaning pass BOD df to each of the parameters of zoo in the position '.' ?

Comment: {...} will ensure that dot is not passed to the first arugument automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Curious where I could learn these advanced usage, so cool!

Comment: Try: `help("%>%", package = "magrittr")` and `vignette("magrittr", package = "magrittr")`